# Variable size array sorter bugging with no reason

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing an algorithm that asks the user to tell the size of an array and then it's values. After it, the code sorts the values and give back the result. The code is as it follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int nvals, k, var, size;

void mysort(int arrayy[]){ 
    int i,j; 
    int temp; 
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) 
        for(j=0;j<size;j++) 
            if(arrayy[j]>arrayy[j+1]){ 
                temp=arrayy[j]; 
                arrayy[j]=arrayy[j+1]; 
                arrayy[j+1]=temp; 
            } 
    cout << "Your sorted array is: [";
    for(i=1;i<10;i++) cout<<arrayy[i]<<", ";
    cout << "].\n";
}

void main(int argc){
    cout << "Number of variables" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    int *arrayy;
    arrayy = new int[size];
    for (int iii=0;iii<size;iii++){
        cout << "Enter number:" << endl;
        cin >> var;
        arrayy[iii] = var;
    }
    mysort(arrayy);
}
```

Unfortunately, after compiling, it outputs `Your sorted array is: [` and then it suddenly crashes! I have been trying to manipulate things to see if I can make it work, but I am not being successful. How can I fix the code so it can work properly? Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `std::vector`? Seeing magical numbers like `10` in here is usually a sign something will go horribly wrong if that bound is exceeded.

Comment: Oh my god. I am an idiot. Just replace all the "10"s with "size" and the code will work fine.

Comment: This is how you learn, so don't worry about it. Using C-style arrays is full of trouble like this. That's why C++ containers are often way, way better. For example, they come with sorting built-in so you don't have to write your own. That bubble-sort isn't going to scale beyond trivial amounts of data.

Comment: @Nobody: You missed a `10` here:    `for(i=1;i<10;i++) cout<<arrayy[i]<<", ";`

Comment: Thank you @BillLynch. Replaced it by `size` and it works ok now. But I am not totally sure about why it works even though it access values like `arrayy[j+1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that `size == 4`.

You'll eventually set `j == 3`, and then access `arrayy[j]` and `arrayy[j+1]`. Accessing `arrayy[j+1]` at that moment provokes undefined behavior because it is outside the array.

Comment: Yes, but then when it prints the array, one can set it to output only the values that were entered. The code will use more memory than what it is supposed to, but it will work fine. Am I right?

Comment: @Nobody: No, since you `arrayy[j+1]` that writes past the end of your array, corrupting random memory.  Which causes the program to crash at some random _completely unrelated point_ down the road.  Like... when printing a number.

Comment: And why is it working fine then? If your thought is right, the code was supposed to be written as `for(i=0;i<(size-1);i++){ and for(j=0;j<(size-1);j++){`, wasn't it?

Comment: @Nobody: Undefined behavior causes undefined behavior. One possible outcome of undefined behavior is that it works fine. But it coudl subtly change over different compilers / time of day.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute all entries of "10" for "size", and you'll get what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int k, size;
void mysort(int arrayy[]){ 

    int i,j; 
    int temp; 
      for(i=0;i<size;i++) 
     for(j=0;j<size;j++) 
      if(arrayy[j]>arrayy[j+1]){ 
         temp=arrayy[j]; 
         arrayy[j]=arrayy[j+1]; 
         arrayy[j+1]=temp; 
       } 
    cout << "Your sorted array is: [";
    for(i=1;i<=size;i++) {
        if (i<size){
            cout<<arrayy[i]<<",";
        }
        else
            cout<<arrayy[i];
    }
    cout << "].\n";
}

void main(int argc){
    cout << "Number of variables" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    int *arrayy;
    arrayy = new int[size];
    for (int iii=0;iii<size;iii++){
        cout << "Enter number:" << endl;
        cin >> arrayy[iii];
    }
    mysort(arrayy);
}
```

Also, I added some formatting lines so your array thing can be well formatted near the second bracket.